# Solving recurrence relations

Tags: recurrence

I honestly don't even know if i am doing this right.  The questions asks to solve:

C0 = 1

CN = CN/2 + N

when N is a power of 2.

Here is what I have so far but it is a complete guess

CN = CN/2 + N

CN/2 = CN/4 + N/2

CN =  CN/4 + N/2 + N

stuck here

Comment: I don't think this is really a programming problem — it's more mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that for each term, you are adding something to the next term. Thus, you'll get a sum. For example, for 1024, you'll get:

```
1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + ...
```

As dividing a nonzero number by two will never yield zero, the base case, C0, is never reached, and you'll end up with an infinite series. Luckily, it is geometric. The initial term is N and each time we multiply by 1/2, so the the sum will be N/(1-1/2) = N/(1/2) = 2N.